# How to return C++ smart pointer to PowerPoint interface using C# Interface

Tags: c#, c++, com, office-interop, smart-pointers

I am making a program partly written in C++ and C#.
C# is mainly used for GUI.
Inside my C++ code I create PowerPoint COM object and open a presentation in it.

At some point I need to reference `PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr` in my C# code. To call methods and so on.

`PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr` is a smart pointer made with

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Presentation, __uuidof(_Presentation));
```

It is defined by Visual studio in msppt.tlh **Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll** binding:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("91493463-5a91-11cf-8700-00aa0060263b"))
/* interface */ PresEvents;
struct /* coclass */ Presentation;

struct __declspec(uuid("9149349d-5a91-11cf-8700-00aa0060263b"))
/* dual interface */ _Presentation;

/* PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr */
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Presentation, __uuidof(_Presentation));
```

So it makes `PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr` for ease of use the COM object in C++, calling methods etc.

And this is C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation

```
namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
{
    [CoClass(typeof(PresentationClass))]
    [Guid("9149349D-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B")]
    public interface Presentation : _Presentation, PresEvents_Event
    {
    }
}
```

I have an Interface in C# with C++ implementation so I can access it in C# part of the application.

**ApplicationHost.cs**

```
namespace SampleWpfUserControlLibrary
{
    public interface IApplicationHostWindow
    {
        void OpenDocument();
        PowerPoint.Presentation GetPresentation();
        void Exit();
    }
}
```

**ApplicastionHost.h**

```
#pragma once
#using <SampleWpfUserControlLibrary.dll>

using namespace SampleWpfUserControlLibrary;

ref class ApplicationHostWrapper : IApplicationHostWindow
{
public:
    ApplicationHostWrapper(CMainFrame * pMainFrame)
    {
        _pMainFrame = pMainFrame;
    }

    virtual void __clrcall Exit() sealed
    {
        _pMainFrame->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
    }

    virtual void __clrcall OpenDocument() sealed
    {
        _pMainFrame->OpenDocument();
    }

    virtual PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr __clrcall GetPresentation() sealed
    {
        CMFCBindDoc * pDoc = _pMainFrame->GetDocView()->GetDocument();
        return pDoc->GetPresentation();
    }
};
```

However it does not compile. Arguing that `GetPresentation()` is not implemented.
As the types do not match.

**Update:**

What should I return in C++ code `PowerPoint::_Presentation` or `PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr` and what should I map it to in C# part? Or How do convert it to Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint in the C#? I just want to reference it in C#.

These are the errors I get:**

> - Error  3   error C2259: 'ApplicationHostWrapper' : cannot instantiate    abstract class
>     Source\Application\MainFrm.cpp    146 1   Application
> - Error  1   error C3766: 'ApplicationHostWrapper' must provide an    implementation for the interface method
>     'Microsoft::Office::Interop::PowerPoint::Presentation
>     ^SampleWpfUserControlLibrary::IApplicationHostWindow::getPresentation(void)'  source\application\ApplicationHostWrapper.h 39  1   Application

In Object Browser getPresentation() method is this:

> unknown-type^ getPresentation()
>       Member of SampleWpfUserControlLibrary::IApplicationHostWindow

Comment: What's the definition of `IApplicationHostWindow`?

Comment: In order to provide communication between managed and unmanaged code I need to keep references between objects. When the user clicks on the Open menu item, the event is handled in C# code, but then the unmanaged code must executed in order to open the presentation file and nest it into the view. it is used as a bridge between managed and unmanaged layers of the application. It's C++/CLI wrapper

Comment: Whatever. The exact definition of the interface and what the compiler says do matter.

Comment: I updated the post, errors added. What do you mean by definition? It's all up there in the post.

Comment: Can a C++ COM smart pointer take the place of a .NET RCW here? If `ApplicationHostWrapper` were implemented in unmanaged C++ as a COM class, returning that smart pointer would be correct, but I'm not sure about doing it in C++/CLI when you're implementing a .NET object. Also, it looks like `Presentation` and `_Presentation` are different interfaces from the C# snippet you posted.

Comment: I updated the question. Explaining all the bindings. This is Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation indeed. But I do not know how to return it to C# when I have this "smart pointer" PowerPoint::_PresentationPtr here it is explained http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx. Or what should I convert it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found solution.
in `ref class ApplicationHostWrapper : IApplicationHostWindow` by calling GetInterfacePtr() on a smart pointer we can get a pointer to interface.

```
virtual void* __clrcall GetPresentationPtr() sealed
{
    CMFCBindDoc * pDoc = _pMainFrame->GetDocView()->GetDocument();
    return (void*)pDoc->GetPresentation().GetInterfacePtr();
}
```

In C# Interface declaration **ApplicationHost.cs:**

```
namespace SampleWpfUserControlLibrary
{
    public interface IApplicationHostWindow
    {
        void OpenDocument();
        unsafe void* GetPresentationPtr();
        void Exit();
    }
}
```

And this allows us to make a method in managed code for example in a class:

```
private IApplicationHostWindow _hostWindow;
unsafe private PowerPoint.Presentation getPresentation(){
   IntPtr preIntPtr = new IntPtr(_hostWindow.GetPresentationPtr());
   return (PowerPoint.Presentation)Marshal.GetUniqueObjectForIUnknown(preIntPtr);
}
```

The only drawback is that it requires using /unsafe for compilation. And what could be the consequences I have no idea yet. If someone knows how to overcome /unsafe and do it differently you are welcome.